# htaccess non-www and non-subdomain to www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using htaccess to redirect non-www to www like this:

- user typea: `mydomain.com`
- .htaccess redirecta to `www.mydomain.com`

My code is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I don't want that redirection when a user enter a subdomain: `help.mydomain.com`

(`help.mydomain.com` is directly sent in mydomain.com root)

Do you have any idea what changes I should do to get this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Here's how:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```